# ANSI C - Clearing a string

Tags: c, ansi-c

I've got a string declared like this:

```
str=malloc(sizeof(char)*128);
```

I want to clear it completely so that whenI do `strncat()` operation, the new characters will be written to  the beginning of `str`. The reason I need to clear it is that I'm writing over it with a simplified version of itself (deleting excess whitespace).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest you simply do this:

```
*str = '\0';
```

You don't need to clear the entire contents of the buffer. You can just set the first `char` to zero and then you have the empty string.

Comment: You beat me to this answer...  He doesn't need to set the **entire** array to 0, so this is much faster.  +1

Answer (score 4):

Use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/):

```
memset(str, 0, sizeof(char)*128);
```

Regardless of this, if you are writing the string over itself, you shouldn't use `strcat` - the objects that you copy must not overlap:

> [If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcat.html)

and a string definitely overlaps with itself.

Removing whitespace from a string can be easily achieved with a simple function:

```
void remove_space(char* r) {
    char *w = r;
    do { *w = *r++; w += *w && !isspace(*w); } while (*w);
}
```

Comment: how do I call `remove_space` function? I tried `char * a = "kk     a";
 remove_space(a);
 printf("[%s]\n", a);` but it returns `Segment fault`.

Comment: @Jack You need to make the string writable: `char a[] = "kk a"; remove_space(a); printf("[%s]\n", a);`

Answer (score 3):

You would like to use [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/) instead of plain `malloc`?

Something like

```
calloc(128, sizeof(char));
```

**EDIT** Also, `strncat` doesn't require you having a null terminated string at the destination. Just make sure that the destination is large enough to hold the concatenated resulting string, including the additional null-character.

And as [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) notes, do not copy overlappingly with `strncat`. Consider using normal `dst[i++] = src[j++]` way of copying.