# Not getting intended output from a C program

Tags: c

I have a program which writes onto a file.  It has a formatting string which it makes beforehand and then use that formatting string to write to a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define LEN_REC_TYPE    5
#define LEN_REC_NO  2
#define LEN_EDI_FILE_ID 5
#define LEN_DATE    8
#define LEN_ST_ARRAY 20



int main()
{
    char  ps_FHEADstring[LEN_ST_ARRAY];
    FILE *pf_edidlord;
    pf_edidlord=fopen("TEST.txt","w");
    char* ps_vdate = "20120101";

    *ps_FHEADstring='\0';
    strcat(ps_FHEADstring,"%-*s");  /* record descriptor */
    strcat(ps_FHEADstring,"%.*ld"); /* line number */
    strcat(ps_FHEADstring,"%-*s");  /* transaction type ind */
    strcat(ps_FHEADstring,"%-*s");  /* file create date */
    strcat(ps_FHEADstring,"\n");

    fprintf(pf_edidlord, ps_FHEADstring,
                         LEN_REC_TYPE,      "FHEAD",
                         LEN_REC_NO,        1,
                         LEN_EDI_FILE_ID,   "DLORD",
                         LEN_DATE,          ps_vdate);



    return 0;
}
```

at the file , the output looks like

```
FHEAD01DLORD20120101
```

notice: there is no "-" in between and why it added a string terminator at the beginning of the string instead of at the end? can someone please explain how it's working?

edit: I printed the `ps_FHEADstring` and the output format is `%-*s%.*ld%-*s%-*s`.  it's a basically a formatting string. so I am expecting a "-" at the output in between.

Comment: What is the output you expected?

Comment: *ps_FHEADstring='\0'

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude soemthing like FHEAD01-DLORD-20120101

Comment: As for the `*ps_FHEADstring='\0'` thing, think about what `strcat` does... It finds the end of the string and if you don't do that assignment there might not be any string terminator in your array.

Comment: So you want the format to be something like `"%*s-%0*d-%*s-%*s"`? Why not use the format explicitly? Why all the `strcat` calls?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  correct me if I am wrong, *ps_FHEADstring means at the start of the String and not at the end. since we are adding other strings after it, it remains at the starting position.

Comment: No your first call to `strcat` overwrites it and add a new terminator at the end.

Comment: @redsoxlost https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193861

Comment: @user202729 added more details in the question.

Comment: Ok, I get it, you misunderstood how `printf` format string works. Unrelated question: Did you write the code yourself?

Comment: @user202729 no, I am just trying to understand a code and I am not that much into C code. 
I checked your link, basically the intention is never to null terminate the string but rather to overwrite it , so that the next iteration starts with an "empty" line or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the format string rules.

`%-*s` writes a string with a max length, defined by a parameter. The `-` is part of the maxlength format, and does not say to write a`-`. If you want a specific character written ,it needs to be outside the format part, for example `"-%-*s"`, or `"-%*s"` if you didn't want the max length functionality.

Comment: thanks for explaining, can you please provide me a link where I can study this functionality.

Comment: @redsoxlost [printf's manual page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777065/5267751).

Comment: @redsoxlost -- go straight to the source with [the C11 Draft Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6)